# UIStoryBoard - Same ViewController/Xib, different segue path

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

This is my scenario: I have an app with TabBar and NavigationController using storyboard. TabBar has item A and item B, both an identical UITableViewController and cells prototypes, it only fetch the info from different locations.

How can I identify from which UIStoryBoardSegue it came? Or there is a better way to do this (maybe duplicate Xib and UIViewController)?

Here a picture of my UIStoryBoard:[image: UIStoryBoard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems strange to have two Navigation Controllers pointing to the same Table View. Why don't you just copy the Table View in the Story Board and use the same class?

Comment: I ended doing this. Copied the Xib in StoryBoard and check which one is by self.navigationItem.title. Thanks!

Comment: Great! :) Much cleaner layout in the Story Board too. Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently working on a project with the same structure and I added two tableviews. But i think it's possible to have one tableview with two different source views. You can try using a navigation controller and when you push to the table view the "back" button will bring you back to the origin.

Comment: I'm starting thinking I'll have to do something like that. Thanks!